# Assigning turtles into groups by color

Tags: netlogo

New to Netlogo, Stackoverflow, and programming in general. I'm wanting to assign turtles to a group based on their color and then report the number of turtles in that group. I'm assigning turtles a color thusly:

set color one-of [13 14 15 23 24 25 43 44 45 63 64 65 93 94 95]

What I want to happen is that turtles within 2 digits of each other would be grouped together, for example turtles with color 13, 14, and 15 would be in a group together. I also want to be able to report the number of turtles in a group using a monitor on the interface tab.

Answer (score 1):

The [`table`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/table.html) extension has the wonderful, super useful, [`table:group-agents`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/table.html#table:group-agents) primitive which is just what you need in this case.

Here is an example of how you could use it:

```
extensions [ table ]
globals [ groups ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [
    set color one-of [13 14 15 23 24 25 43 44 45 63 64 65 93 94 95]
  ]
  set groups table:group-agents turtles [ color - color mod 10 ]
  print groups
  foreach (range 10 100 10) [ g ->
    let turtles-in-group table:get-or-default groups g no-turtles
    print (word count turtles-in-group " turtles in group " g)
  ]
end
```

The key line here is

```
set groups table:group-agents turtles [ color - color mod 10 ]
```

The `color - color mod 10` part is just a little trick to transform a color like 23 into a "round" color like 20. Turtles that have the same value that expression get put into the same group. The result of running this code will be something like:

```
{{table: [[60 (agentset, 19 turtles)] [10 (agentset, 32 turtles)] [90 (agentset, 19 turtles)] [20 (agentset, 20 turtles)] [40 (agentset, 10 turtles)]]}}
32 turtles in group 10
20 turtles in group 20
0 turtles in group 30
10 turtles in group 40
0 turtles in group 50
19 turtles in group 60
0 turtles in group 70
0 turtles in group 80
19 turtles in group 90
```

As you can see, it's possible to extract all the information you need from the table. It's worth familiarizing yourself with how tables work if you haven't played with them before.

I don't know what you plan to do with this in the end, but it might be worth creating a `my-group` variable for your turtles. Supposing you have

```
turtles-own [ my-group ]
```

at the top of your code, you can do something like:

```
foreach table:keys groups [ g ->
  ask table:get groups g [
    set my-group table:get groups g
  ]
]
```

which then makes it easy to do stuff like:

```
ask one-of turtles [ create-link-with one-of other my-group ]
```

Links, by the way, are also a good thing to familiarize yourself with if you are new to NetLogo.

When I work with turtles that are members of groups, I often use a `groups` turtle breed to represent the group and create links between individual turtles and the group they belong to. This is especially useful if you have "group level" attributes that you need to keep track of. I'd be happy to expand on this, but I think this is starting to be beyond the scope of this particular answer...